# String to date conversion issue in PHP5.6

Tags: php, date

```
date('m/d/Y', strtotime('7-Jan-69'))
```

It gives output as `01/07/2069`, Where

```
date('m/d/Y', strtotime('7-Jan-75'))
```

This gives output as `01/07/1975`, Why is so and what is the catch?

Comment: `the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC` 1969 is before 1970

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds **since January 1 1970** 00:00:00 UTC)

Any date before 1970 will be understand as date after 1970

Comment: This issue is unrelated to timestamps though. strtotime can output negative timestamps. It just so happens that the 2-digit year cut-off is also 1970.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/NUsVC

Comment: That's true. By not having "complete"  year information, the function understand that is a future date, not in the past.

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like this?

```
<? 
    // function to convert string and print 
    function convertString ($date) 
    { 
        // convert date and time to seconds 
        $sec = strtotime($date); 

        // convert seconds into a specific format 
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i", $sec); 

        // append seconds to the date and time 
        $date = $date . ":00"; 

        // print final date and time 
        echo $date; 
    } 

    // Driver code 
    $date = "06/12/2014 04:13 PM"; 
    convertString($date); 
?>
```

Comment: Nice code, but it doesn't answer the specific question as to why a '69' is interpreted as 2069 and '75' as 1975

Answer (score 0):

To fix that you can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead of `strtotime()` like below,

```
<?php
$date = $dt = new DateTime('7-Jan-75');
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');
?>
```

**Reason for not working in your case with strtotime:**

> If the number of the year is specified in a two digit format, the values between 00-69 are mapped to 2000-2069 and 70-99 to 1970-1999.
>   See the notes below for possible differences on 32bit systems
>   (possible dates might end on 2038-01-19 03:14:07).

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/d8eoK